# script as UIWebView url

Tags: ios, uiwebview

how to load script for uiwebview as url?

I try this:

```
-(IBAction)rulButtonPressed:(id)sender{
    [_webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"#1 onclick=s=document.createElement('script');s.src='http://sidio.ru/rul/last30.js.php?'+Math.random();document.body.appendChild(s);"]]];

}
```

but its now working

I need to load it as url after pressing button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is a bit vague, but you probably want to use one of these:

```
[_webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:(NSString *)];
[_webView loadHTMLString:(NSString *) baseURL:(NSURL *)];
```

[UIWebView Docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html)
[UIWebViewDelegate Protocol Docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html)

---

Something like this might work for you:

```
- (IBAction)rulButtonPressed:(id)sender {
    [_webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.createElement('script');s.src='http://sidio.ru/rul/last30.js.php?'+Math.random();document.body.appendChild(s);"]; 
}
```

Comment: Ok, I need to load this javascript: onclick=s=document.createElement('script');s.src='http://sidio.ru/rul/last30.js.php?'+Math.random();document.body.appendChild(s);    when I tap button rulButtonPressed

Comment: You could probably do something like this in the ` - (IBAction)rulButtonPressed:(id)sender {  [_webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.createElement('script');s.src='http://sidio.ru/rul/last30.js.php?'+Math.random();document.body.appendChild(s);"]; }`

Comment: Very cool!  Glad you got it working @nik1004!  Feel free to click the "checkmark" to the left to "accept the answer".